# Call Object method from another method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object, methods, call

this problem should be easy to solve but im pulling my hair in this..

```
function Class() {
 this.isCordova = function () {
     if (typeof cordova === 'undefined') {
         return false;
     } else {
         return true;
     }
 }

 this.loadMainLayout = function () {

     if (!isCordova()) {
         //More code
     }
 }
```

It gives me an error when i call

> !isCordova

Uncaught ReferenceError: isCordova is not defined

i know its a dumb method reference error but i cant find the solution to this as i already tried "this.isCordova()","self.isCordova()" and "Class.isCordova()".
thanks!

Comment: Looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/DYExw/

Comment: or you can avoid 'this' in both methods to work it without a this  !